# How do I make my objects less messy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

My project has three main parts to it:

- Pages (similar to articles)
- Categories (the pages have a category associated with them)
- Tags (each Page can have several different tags)

I have a sidebar which uses @categories to pull through a list of all the current categories in my project:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p class="lead">Categories</p>
  <div class="list-group">
    <%= link_to 'All articles', pages_path(@page), :class => 'list-group-item' %>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <%= link_to category.name, category_path(category), :class => 'list-group-item' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

But currently I need to include

```
@categories = Category.all
```

In my index and show actions in my controllers for both pages and categories so that the sidebar loads (I only use the sidebar in these two parts of the project).

Is there an easier way of doing this than including the above code in every action in the controller?

Also with the tags controller after creating a page and going to the tag's show page to view any pages associated with those tags, I get an error saying 'Couldn't find page with 'id'=2.

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @tags = Tag.all
end

def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.all
end
```

-

```
<% @tag.pages.each do |page| %>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="text">
      <article class="clearfix">
        <%= link_to page.title, url_for_page(page), class: "h1" %>
        <p class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on <%= page.created_at.to_formatted_s :long %></p>
        <hr />
        <%= page.body.html_safe %>
        <hr />
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group" aria-label="...">
          <% page.tags.each do |tag| %>
            <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), class: "btn btn-info" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Anyone got any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Update:

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories
  resources :pages
  resources :tags
```

Models:
Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pages
```

Page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Bootsy::Container
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings

    def tag_list
        self.tags.collect do |tag|
            tag.name
        end.join(", ")
    end

    def tag_list=(tags_string)
        tag_names = tags_string.split(", ").collect{ |s| s.strip.downcase }.uniq
        new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect { |name|         Tag.find_or_create_by(name: name) }
        self.tags = new_or_found_tags
    end
end
```

Tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Bootsy::Container
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :pages, through: :taggings

    def to_s
        name
    end
end
```

Tagging.rb

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Bootsy::Container   
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :page
end
```

Comment: Is it a typo or do Tag and Page really share the same id from the request?

Comment: Where abouts are you looking? It's probably staring me straight in the eye but I can't see where I've gone wrong :p

Comment: In tags#index you are using `@tag = Tag.find(params[:id])` and `@page = Page.find(params[:id])`, so page and tag go along with the same identifiers?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a before_action for the controller limited to only index and show actions, as below:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_categories, only: [:index, :show]

  # Your code

  private

  def load_categories
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

That will load the categories into the instance variable for both the index and show actions.

For the error you're getting, if I'm reading it right you have nested routes? You need to be getting the correct ID for the tag, which is :tag_id:

```
def show
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:tag_id])
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

You were getting :id for both. If that doesn't work, are your routes nested? If not post your routes and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Are you on about my routes.rb file? I've updated my question with the current routes, I haven't set up any nesting within there yet, I've changed the params to :tag_id but it doesn't seem to have changed it. Cheers

Comment: OK so they aren't nested. The show action for a standard resource that isn't nested is it has one :id in the params, so when you go /tags/2 that 2 should be the tag id. Where should the post id be coming from? I'm unclear how you are trying to find that specific page object from the params

Comment: I've updated my original post with the models of my project (sorry if this is kinda long or confusing), each page can have many tags, and I'm wanting to be able to see all the pages associated with each tag by clicking on the tag in the page index/show pages, and the category show page

Comment: Sorry I was finished for the day yesterday. There is quite a lot to this answer now, we need to change the routes and add a new controller. Are you still struggling with this? I don't want to write it all out if you've already done it!

Comment: Haven't cracked it yet, if you're willing to help that'd be amazing, you've already helped so much, I don't want to feel like I'm taking up too much time, I feel like once I've figured out where I'm going wrong I'll be able to work on that, cheers :)

Comment: OK. Can you confirm the objects are associated properly in the database first? If you do 'rails console' from the command line, and then do something like Tag.last.pages - does it return the expected pages? I.e, are you creating the objects correctly and we're just trying to show them now.

Comment: It looks like the association is in place, Tag.last.pages shows the following: 
    Tag Load(0.0ms) SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" ORDER BY "tags"."id" DESC LIMIT 1

Page Load(0.0ms) SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "pages"."id" = "taggings"."page_id" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = ?

Comment: The SQL looks right but does that return any actual results from tags/pages you have created?

Answer (score 0):

You can [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) out your Controller to set page and categories in a callback. But take care: you may omit the categories query in the categories#index action, but your page#... actions may skip the callback at all `skip_before_action set_page` or better overwrite the method and use a correct handling.

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action set_page, only: [:index, :show]
  before_action set_categories, only: [:index, :show]

  private
  def set_page
   @page = Page.find params[:page_id]
  end

  def set_categories
   @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```